# Extracting ROW Data type names from SQL (Athena)

Tags: sql, row, amazon-athena

I am using Amazon Athena (AWS) and am wanting to grab the ROW data names from this column.

This is an example of what my current dataset looks like:

[image]

And this is the output I desire:

[image]

So I just want to get the ROW names, if possible. I did try casting to JSON but it removes all the ROW names.

Comment: This document would help you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html

Comment: You can also try something like this: WITH dataset AS ( SELECT '{STR= {description = Type}}' AS ROWTYPE ) SELECT replace(split(ROWTYPE,'=')[1],'{','') a FROM dataset